# Forgot to do git flow feature start; what now?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-flow

My local repository is on branch `develop`.

We're using Git Flow and I'm supposed to work on a new feature on a separate branch. Normally, I'd do `git flow feature start "whatever"` before commiting my changes; this time, however, I forgot. Fortunatelly I didn't push this mess yet.

Now I can obviously rescue the situation by (a) copy-pasting my current work to another directory (b) undoing my last unpushed commits from `develop`; (c) issuing `git flow feature start "whatever"`; (d) copy-pasting my work from this other directory onto my local git repo; (e) re-commiting.

I'm curious, however, if this can be avoided? That is: if I can create this branch I did not create on time and move my commits and current work to this branch without copy-pasting files? What git commands would I have to issue to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

`git stash` to save current state

`git reset --hard <hash>` to reset to previous commit

`git checkout -b feature/awesome-feature` to create a new branch

`git stash apply` to reapply all your work

Now, you should have all your work in your feature branch with a clean master branch

Answer (score 0):

If your develop branch is not yet pushed to origin, do it this way:

1. commit all your updates to the branch you are working right now. e.g `develop`.

   - **Commit only not sync**
2. Create a new feature branch base on your current local `develop` branch. `feature/"whatever"`
3. Then hard reset your local `develop` branch base on your `origin/develop`.

**Conclusion:** This way you won't rewrite all your changes, the develop branch is the same as before, there is not additional stashes, git flow recognizes the changes you made and it works perfectly even when you already committed several changes to your local develop branch.